# Get the date information of a .pbf file

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to check whether a .pbf file is up to date. Are there any methods to acquire such a kind of information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `osmconvert` See the documentation here for download links and installation instructions for your platform http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert

Once you have it installed, from the command line run `osmconvert mydata.osm.pbf --out-statistics` That will include the timestamp, assuming the tool that created the PBF set it correctly.

To make sure it is up to date, you can also use the `osmupdate` command to update a PBF with the latest data from OSM. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmupdate

Comment: Thanks a lot. `osmconvert` is what I want. I thought to use `osmupdate` but I found that it cost time and I couldn't get the information directly.

Comment: Note that `osmconvert --out-statistics` analyzes the entire file and can be **very slow for large files**. If all you need is a timestamp, `osmium` is the way to go (see mar's answer).

Answer (score 3):

Just use the osmium-tool, the example command is:

"osmium fileinfo poland-latest.osm.pbf"

The result:
File:
Name: poland-latest.osm.pbf
Format: PBF
Compression: none
Size: 988380826
Header:
Bounding boxes: (14.0998,48.9857,24.1652,55.0995)
With history: no
Options:
generator=osmium/1.5.1
osmosis_replication_base_url=http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/poland-updates
osmosis_replication_sequence_number=1486
osmosis_replication_timestamp=2017-04-13T20:43:02Z
pbf_dense_nodes=true
timestamp=2017-04-13T20:43:02Z